# Erro 1452 Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Estou iniciando em mysql, então não reparem nas tabelas mal feitas.
Enfim tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
    create table Alunos (
MAT int,
nome varchar (45),
endereco varchar (45),
cidade varchar (45),
constraint primary key (MAT)
);

create table Disciplinas (
COD_DISC int,
nome_disc varchar (45) not null,
carga_hor int,
primary key (COD_DISC)
);

create table Professores (
COD_PROF int,
nome varchar (45) not null,
endereco varchar (45),
cidade varchar (45),
primary key (COD_PROF)
);

create table Turma(
COD_DISC int,
COD_TURMA int,
COD_PROF int,
disci varchar (5),
ano int,
horario varchar (45),
primary key (COD_TURMA,COD_DISC,COD_PROF,ano),
constraint FK_Disc foreign key (COD_DISC) references Disciplinas (COD_DISC),
constraint FK_Prof foreign key (COD_PROF) references Professores (COD_PROF)
);

create table if not exists Historico (
MAT int,
COD_DISC int,
COD_TURMA int,
COD_PROF int,
ano int,
frequencia int,
nota int,
primary key (MAT,COD_DISC,COD_TURMA,COD_PROF,ano),
constraint FK_histalun foreign key (MAT) references Alunos (MAT),
constraint FK_histfisc foreign key (COD_DISC,COD_TURMA,COD_PROF,ano) references Turma (COD_Disc,COD_TURMA,COD_PROF,ano)
);
```

E adicionei os seguintes dados:

```
insert into Alunos values 
('2015010101', 'JOSE DE ALENCAR', 'RUA DAS ALMAS', 'NATAL'),
('2015010102', 'JOÃO JOSÉ', 'AVENIDA RUY CARNEIRO', 'JOÃO PESSOA'),
('2015010103', 'MARIA JOAQUINA', 'RUA CARROSSEL', 'RECIFE'),
('2015010104', 'MARIA DAS DORES', 'RUA DAS LADEIRAS', 'FORTALEZA'),
('2015010105', 'JOSUÉ CLAUDINO DOS SANTOS', 'CENTRO', 'NATAL'),
('2015010106', 'JOSUÉLISSON CLAUDINO DOS SANTOS', 'CENTRO', 'NATAL');



insert into Disciplinas values
(1, 'BANCO DE DADOS', '100'),
(2, 'PROGRAMAÇÃO COM ACESSO A BANCO DE DADOS', '100'),
(3, 'AUTORIA WEB', '50'),
(4, 'ENGENHARIA DE SOFTWARE', '80')
;

insert into Professores values 
('212131', 'NICKERSON FERREIRA', 'RUA MANAÍRA', 'JOÃO PESSOA'),
('122135', 'ADORILSON BEZERRA', 'AVENIDA SALGADO FILHO', 'NATAL'),
('192011', 'DIEGO OLIVEIRA', 'AVENIDA ROBERTO FREIRE', 'NATAL')

;


insert into Turma values
(1, '1', '212131', 'BD', '2015', '11H-12H'),
(1, '2', '212131', 'BD', '2015', '13H-14H'),
(2, '1', '192011', 'POO', '2015', '08H-09H'),
(3, '1', 192011, 'WEB', '2015', '07H-08H'),
(4, '1', 122135, 'ENG', '2015', '10H-11H');
```

Mas quando tento colocar os dados na tabela histórico:

```
insert into Historico values 
('2015010101', '1', '1', '212131', '2015', '100', '10'),
('2015010102', '2', '2', '122135', '2015', '75', '7'),
('2015010103', '3', '2', '122135', '2016', '45', '2'),
('2015010104', '4', '1', '192011', '2016', '75', '4'),
('2015010105', '4', '1', '212131', '2014', '60', '3'),
('2015010101', '4', '1', '212131', '2015', '100', '9'),
('2015010102', '1', '2', '122135', '2015', '75', '7'),
('2015010103', '2', '3', '122135', '2016', '45', '2'),
('2015010104', '3', '4', '192011', '2016', '75', '6'),
('2015010105', '4', '5', '212131', '2014', '60', '3'),
('2015010101', '4', '1', '212131', '2015', '100', '10'),
('2015010102', '4', '2', '122135', '2015', '75', '7'),
('2015010103', '1', '3', '122135', '2016', '45', '2'),
('2015010104', '2', '4', '192011', '2016', '75', '6'),
('2015010105', '3', '5', '212131', '2014', '60', '3'),
('2015010101', '3', '1', '212131', '2015', '100', '10'),
('2015010102', '4', '2', '122135', '2015', '75', '7'),
('2015010103', '4', '3', '122135', '2016', '45', '1'),
('2015010104', '1', '4', '192011', '2016', '75', '4'),
('2015010105', '2', '5', '212131', '2014', '60', '3'),
('2015010101', '2', '1', '212131', '2015', '100', '10'),
('2015010102', '3', '2', '122135', '2015', '75', '7'),
('2015010103', '4', '3', '122135', '2016', '45', '2'),
('2015010104', '4', '4', '192011', '2016', '75', '4'),
('2015010105', '1', '5', '212131', '2014', '60', '3');
```

Começa da o error 1452 cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails, alguem sabe o que há de errado com as chaves estrangeiras?

Answer (score 1):

na sua segunda linha de insert dos históricos, já tem um erro:

```
('2015010102', '2', '2', '122135', '2015', '75', '7'),
```

a tabela de histórico tem uma chave estrangeira onde, `COD_DISC,COD_TURMA,COD_PROF,ano` obrigatoriamente tem que existir na tabela de turmas.

assim, no trecho asima citado, não é correspondente a nenhum registro na tabela de turma.

Ou seja, na tabela de turma, você não tem um registro como esse:

```
(2, '2', 122135, 'ENG', '2015', '10H-11H');
```

ps. Já parei a verificação na segunda linha, as outras nem cheguei a verificar.

Coloquei também no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff45e0